# Group, do we have $(A\times B)^*=A^*\times B^*$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $A,B$ two group. I denote the group of unit of $A$ and $B$ by $A^*
$ and $B^*$. Do we always have 
$$(A\times B)^*=A^*\times B^*$$ ?

Comment: You mean that A,B are monoids, or rings? The group of units of a group is the group itsself.

Comment: Acctually I want to show that $$(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^*=(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^*\times (\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^*$$

Comment: Yes, and here $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is considered *as a ring*. Try to prove $(A \times B)^* =A^* \times B^*$ for arbitrary two rings $A,B$, you won't have any difficulties when you use the definitions.

Comment: Can I do like this: let $[a]=([b],[c])\in (A\times B)^*$, therefore, there is $[d]=([e],[f])$ such that $(1,1)=[a][d]=([b],[c])([e],[f])$. But do we have that $$([b],[c])([e],[f])=([b][e],[c][f])$$ ?

Comment: Why brackets? Take any two rings, abstract from residue class rings. As for your question: Recall the *definition* of the product of two rings.